# Django : CSRF verification failed. request aborted

Tags: django, csrf-protection

I'm currently viewing Django documentaion for creating a Form with post method(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/). But, I get a `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted` error while 
executing the `vote()` function in views.py

files being used are:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Question
.
.
.
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk = 
request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, choice.DoesNotExitst):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html',{
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "you didn't select a choice"
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args= 
(question.id)))
```

detail.html:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{%if error_message%}<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{%endif%}

<form action="{%url 'polls:vote' question.id%}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{%for choice in question.choice_set.all%}
    <input type = "radio" name = "choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter 
}}" value = "{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{choice.choice_text}} 
</label><br>
{%endfor%}
<input type="submit" value="vote">
</form>
```

results.html:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{%for choice in question.choice_set.all%}
    <li>{{choice.choice_text}} -- {{choice.votes}} 
vote{{choice.votes|pluralize}}</li>
{&endfor&}
</ul>

<a href="{%url 'polls:detail question.id'%}">Vote again?</a>
```

these are the MIDDLEWAREs used:

```
`MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

urls.py:

```
.
.
.
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

yet I get this error:

[image]

Comment: you getting this everytime or just got onces? and can you also provide urls.py

Comment: @shekhar i'm getting this everytime. (urls.py included)

Comment: for once try to copy hole code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form and  then do vote, see if anything diffferent comes up. Because I think if csrf is failing then its either because of template or settings